# How to get a "-exec"-functionality of the find-command in the tree-command?

Tags: linux, tree, find, exec

With `find ... -exec ...` one can get a list of certain files and execute a command on each of these files.

Now I'd like to have a list of files in the `tree`-style and also execute a command on each of theses files, and have the result printed after the filename; e.g. like:

+-- pic1.gif : 1200x900
+-- pic2.txt : 54, title
`-- pic3.png : 800x400

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not shell executing the command, it is using Linux’s `exec` directly to execute the command. This means that any shell expansion won’t work here as you don’t have a shell. Another effect is the unavailability of shell functions or aliases.

As a workaround for missing shell functions, it is export them and call `bash -c` with requested function on file.
create a shell function that shows the track name and some details about the quality:

```
function mp3info() {
    TRACK_NAME=$(basename "$1")
    FILE_DATA=$(file "$1" | awk -F, '{$1=$2=$3=$4=""; print $0 }')
    echo "${TRACK_NAME%.mp3} : $FILE_DATA"
}
```

If we’ll try to run the mp3info command on all of our files, `-exec` will complain it doesn’t know about `mp3info`:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec mp3info {} \;
find: ‘mp3info’: No such file or directory
```

Just export shell function and run it as part of a spawned shell:

```
$ export -f mp3info
$ find . -name "*.mp3" -exec bash -c "mp3info \"{}\"" \;
01 - Das Trinklied vom Jammer der Erde :      128 kbps  44.1 kHz  Stereo
02 - Der Einsame im Herbst :      128 kbps  44.1 kHz  Stereo
03 - Von der Jugend :      128 kbps  44.1 kHz  Stereo
04 - Von der Schönheit :      128 kbps  44.1 kHz  Stereo
05 - Der Trunkene im Frühling :      128 kbps  44.1 kHz  Stereo
06 - Der Abschied :      128 kbps  44.1 kHz  Stereo
```

Note that because some of our filenames hold spaces it is need to quote the results placeholder.

The results placeholder is denoted by **two curly braces** `{}`.

Use the placeholder multiple times if necessary:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec bash -c "basename \"{}\" && file \"{}\" | awk -F: '{\$1=\"\"; print \$0 }'" \;
01 - Das Trinklied vom Jammer der Erde.mp3
  Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
02 - Der Einsame im Herbst.mp3
  Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
03 - Von der Jugend.mp3
  Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
04 - Von der Schönheit.mp3
  Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
05 - Der Trunkene im Frühling.mp3
  Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
06 - Der Abschied.mp3
  Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
```

We need to provide the `find` command with a **delimiter** so it’ll know where our -exec arguments stop.

Two types of delimiters can be provided to the `-exec` argument: the semi-colon(**;**) or the plus sign (**+**).

We don’t want our shell to interpret the semi-colon, so we need to escape it like this (;).

The delimiter determines the way find handles the expression results. If we use the semi-colon (;), the `-exec` command will be repeated for each result separately. On the other hand, if we use the plus sign (+), all of the expressions’ results will be concatenated and passed as a whole to the `-exec` command which will run only once.

Let’s show the usage of the plus sign with another example:

```
$ find . -name "*.mp3" -exec echo {} +
./Gustav Mahler/01 - Das Trinklied vom Jammer der Erde.mp3 ./Gustav Mahler/02 -
  Der Einsame im Herbst.mp3 ./Gustav Mahler/03 - Von der Jugend.mp3 ./Gustav Mahler/04 -
  Von der Schönheit.mp3 ./Gustav Mahler/05 - Der Trunkene im Frühling.mp3
  ./Gustav Mahler/06 - Der Abschied.mp3
```

When running `echo`, a newline is generated for every echo call, but since we used the plus-delimiter, only a single echo call was made. Let’s compare this result to the semi-colon version:

```
$ find . -name "*.mp3" -exec echo {} \;
./Gustav Mahler/01 - Das Trinklied vom Jammer der Erde.mp3
./Gustav Mahler/02 - Der Einsame im Herbst.mp3
./Gustav Mahler/03 - Von der Jugend.mp3
./Gustav Mahler/04 - Von der Schönheit.mp3
./Gustav Mahler/05 - Der Trunkene im Frühling.mp3
./Gustav Mahler/06 - Der Abschied.mp3
```

From a performance point of view, we’ll usually prefer to use the plus-sign delimiter, as running separate processes for each file can incur a serious penalty in both RAM and processing time.

We might prefer using the semi-colon delimiter in one of the following cases:

- The tool run by -exec does not accept multiple files as an argument
- Running the tool on so many files at once might use up too much memory
- We want to start getting some results as soon as possible, even though it will take more time to get all the results

Good luck in bash exercises.

Comment: I have already seen exact this information on other places, thanks; but my question is not about the exec itself but about how to apply the exec-mechanism to the tree-command instead of to the find-command.

Answer (score 0):

Since tree result is text. It is possible to filter its content and extract the file names from the tree.

```
tree . | grep -o " [[:alnum:]\.-\_]\+"
```

In order to apply a command on each file. Suggesting to loop on each found file in a `for loop` command. Executing `your_command` on each file:

```
for file in $(tree . | grep -o " [[:alnum:]\.-\_]\+"); do your_command "$file"; done
```

Comment: This does not give an output in tree-format (tree-style).

Comment: It's just another way (here via 'find') to get all specific filenames in (and under) this directory and do something with it. This could also be done with 'find'.

Comment: By the way, I have to use 'grep -o " [[:alnum:]_\.\-]\+"' to not get filenames splitted when they include "-".